# how to filter a django model using IN for a list that includes None

Tags: django, django-models

I have a view based on a model where the user can filter the items model based on the categories field using:

```
Items.objects.filter(categories__in=[‘A’, ’B’, ‘C’])
```

However in come cases the categories field is NULL, and the user may would like to see the list of NULL and A categories. So I have tried:

```
Items.objects.filter(categories__in=[None, ‘A’])
```

But this does not see to work and my result only shows for A,B and C

This is, of course, a simplified view of the issue as the list is dynamic and there are so many other filters as well.

But the principle is the same, how can include None in the list of IN operation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Items.objects.filter(Q(categories__in=[‘A’, ’B’, ‘C’]) | Q(categories__isnull=True))
```